# How to convert the contents of an entry widget (which has a string data type by default) to an integer?

Tags: python

I have tried to do this in the following way:

```
from tkinter import*

# creates a GUI
Tester = Tk()

# gives the mainframe a title
Tester.title("")

NonEssentialFoodEntry = Entry(Tester, width="30")

NonEssentialFoodEntry.place(x=300,y=540)

NonEssentialFood = ""

NonEssentialFood = NonEssentialFoodEntry.get()

NonEssentialFood = int(NonEssentialFood)

def checker():
    if NonEssentialFood <0:
        print(' negative number entered')

# assigns attributes to button
Checker=Button(Tester, height="7",width="30",font=300,command=checker)

# displays and places button
Checker.place(x=700, y=580)

    NonEssentialFood = int(NonEssentialFood)
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''
>>>
```

I think there may be a particular way to convert the contents of an entry widget, to a integer, but I'm not sure why. (the contents of entry widgets are string by default).

Comment: You are calling `NonEssentialFoodEntry.get()` *immediately* after creating the Entry; how could it possibly have any contents yet?  You need to do that later, in `checker()` probably.

Comment: For dealing with Integer inputs there is a special tkinter `tkinter.IntVar()` available that you can add as an input to the function that makes `NonEssentialFoodEntry`

Answer (score 1):

You should convert the contents of the entry only when the user presses your button, for example

```
def checker():
    try:
        user_input = int(NonEssentialFoodEntry.get())
    except ValueError:
        # Deal with non numeric inputs here
    if user_input < 0:
        print('Negative number entered')
```